# Error uploading iOS binary: Non-public API usage

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect

Trying to upload an app to itunesconnected but get this error:

```
Non-public API usage:
The app references non-public symbols in B: _dispatch_benchmark
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have a look here : http://nshipster.com/benchmarking/ There are few lines about it, might help.

Answer (score 2):

Did you use `dispatch_benchmark()` in your app? It's private API and cannot be used in a shipping app. Besides which, you shouldn't have benchmarking code in a shipping app anyway—keep the debug stuff in debug builds. Luckily, you can use the preprocessor to remove the offending code for release builds only:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    //Your debug-only code, including dispatch_benchmark(), here
#endif
```

Comment: Nope, I don't use it, so it's strange, and Apple have never complained about this before. Might be an IOS9 bugg, or maybe some of my Pods have it?

Comment: I'd guess that a pod is using it if you aren't directly.